# Running testcontainers on Jenkins (AKS) inside Docker image

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, azure-aks, testcontainers

I am trying to run a Jenkins pipeline to run my testcase. My testcase uses testcontainer frameworks. Jenkins has been installed over Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

When I try to execute the pipeline, Azure doesnt allow modifiy Docker socket, and this command doesnt work:

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Reading AKS guidelines, I found next comment in Container limitations:

***You can no longer access the docker engine, /var/run/docker.sock, or use Docker-in-Docker (DinD).***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#containerd-limitationsdifferences

How can I map Docker socket using AKS in order to execute docker images // testcontainer? Its possible to use testcontainers over AKS or I would need to change my cloud?

Comment: You need to host a remote Docker daemon somewhere and you can then configure it using https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-docker-host-detection. You can also try out Testcontainers Cloud, which provides exactly this experience without any additional setup: https://www.testcontainers.cloud/

Answer (score -1):

According to [the Testcontainers documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/):

> Testcontainers requires a Docker-API compatible container runtime.

This isn't available in Kubernetes, as you note, and it means you can't use Testcontainers in a Kubernetes-hosted CI system.

You might consider breaking up your test suite into a set of pure unit tests and separate integration tests.  The unit tests don't depend on containers or any other external resources, possibly using stub implementations of interfaces or mocks of external API calls; they necessarily only simulate reality, but can run anywhere your build system runs.  The integration tests would depend on a fully-deployed application and make API calls to your container's endpoints.  This split would let you avoid needing to run external dependencies in the unit-test phase, and thereby avoid Testcontainers.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I need integration tests in order to tests hibernate and 2 or more SQL engines of my app, because my app currently uses 2 SQL engines. I already have unit test for tests atomic functions and I cover end to end tests with testcontainer framework.

Comment: > "This isn't available in Kubernetes, as you note, and it means you can't use Testcontainers in a Kubernetes-hosted CI system."

This is not correct, since you can use Testcontainers with a remote Docker host and k8s allows to run pods that expose Docker as well.